# Maintaining a vector of a maximum size?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

This works for keeping my vector length under the `max_size` that I've chosen, and I haven't been able to make it break with my testing, but is the method of limiting vector size safe?

```
  if (vector.size() >= max_size) {
    vector.erase(vector.begin());
  }
```

It is for an undo/redo state so I only want to keep a finite number of states in memory.

Comment: So long as you have only one thread, it's impossible to add more than one item at a time, and you don't do while while iterating, yes. Off topic: Consider using [`std::deque` instead.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) It should have better performance for this use, but it won't be contiguous memory.

Comment: See [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).  What you're describing is, as one answer already pointed out, is a *ring* or *circular buffer*, even though you were not aware of it.

Comment: Okay, thank you I will look into those options.  It's a reasonably small set, 50 8 byte types, and is accessed at a max speed of user click input, but it is probably good practise to optimise when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will work (assuming you add elements one at a time), but it's not going to be very fast. The `std::vector` type is optimized for insertions and deletions on the end, not the beginning, and the cost of removing the first element can be high if you have a large number of elements in the `std::vector`. If you're keeping a large buffer, it might be better to use a `std::deque`, which optimized for deletions at the front and end (precisely your use case.)

For what it's worth, you may want to look up the term "circular buffer," which is the sort of data structure that you're logically talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This method will not work if the `std::vector` is increased by more than one element before your method is called as your method only removes one element if the `std::vector` is larger the `max_size`.

The following code will remove a range of elements according to how many extra elements there are in the `std::vector`.

```
if (vector.size() >= max_size)
{
    auto elements_to_erase = (vector.size() - max_size) + 1;
    vector.erase(vector.begin(), vector.begin() + elements_to_erase);
}
```

Comment: This is the first part of the only method that adds to the vector, so I don't think I will run into that issue, but I will take that into account for future vector use.